# Express catch-all route with optional first parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How to implement route (middleware) that will be called on every request, but in same time it should catch optional `lang` parameter.

So far I tried code below, but it doesn't work. Most likely problem in path-matching (`/:lang*?`). In code below `lang` param is undefined:

```
const SUPPORTED_LOCALES = ['en', 'fr', 'de'];

expressServer.use('/:lang*?', function(req, res, next) {
   // check if known locale, if no then fallback to 'en'
   const locale = SUPPORTED_LOCALES.includes((req.params.lang)) ? req.params.lang : 'en'; 
   req.locale = locale;
   next();
}
```

This middleware should catch absolutely all requests, even just domain name (in case of locale is not provided it will fallback to default locale `en`):

```
example.com
example.com/de/blog/2
example.com/fr
example.com/en
example.com/en/blog/1
example.com/blog/1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `app.use` without a path

```js
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Time: %d', Date.now())
  next()
})
```

Example from [Express app.use](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.use)

Not sure if this work but the language code in your cases 2 characters long. So with `regex` as first parameter you can specify all routes with two characters.

```js
app.use('/\/^([a-z]){2}$/', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('Language:', req.originalUrl.substr(1));
  next();
})
```

`req.originalUrl` returns for example `/en`. To remove the slash just remove it with `substr`.

Comment: Ye, thanks. I just want not to bother with `req.params.split()[1]`. Also need to check that array length is more >= 1. I don't want to write too much code.